# Why is a function with a long name faster than the same small name function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
import time

def e(x):
    return x**x

def ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ(x):
    return x**x

a = 0
start = time.process_time_ns()
a = e(7)
lap = time.process_time_ns()
a = ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ(7)
end = time.process_time_ns()
print(lap-start)
print(end-lap)
```

I was testing to see if the name of a python function determined call speed, but surprisingly, `e()` is much slower than `Z()`. I even defined the variable before timing, but `Z()` is still faster. Why is that?

Comment: That's not a robust way to determine performance. Use `timeit`; I get `e` *maybe* slightly faster, but not by much.

Comment: That's not a reliable way to time.  The performance is identical using `timeit`: `In [32]: %timeit e(100)
842 ns ± 12.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [33]: %timeit ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ(100)
834 ns ± 12.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

Comment: It isn't. Your timing method is flawed and biased by the fact that a modern OS is not just holding it's breath when you run a program. Your computer is always busy with a lot of different things, and those take time too. Use the `timeit` module to account for that and take multiple measures.

Comment: I'll try it out

Comment: Switch the order of the calls, and you'll find that whichever one comes first takes longer. You're timing startup costs.

Comment: @user2357112 what are the startup costs? Trailing processes from a=0?

Comment: @TyStaszak: Hard to say. I'd guess something allocation-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not any slower practically. In order to get accurate timing you need to run multiple times. In Jupyter, you can use the magic `%%timeit` at the top of a cell to do this for you. I get:

```
a = e(7)
436 ns ± 21.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

a = ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ(7)
426 ns ± 13.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Or, manually:

```
n_iter = 1000000
start = time.process_time()
for i in range(n_iter):
    e(7)  # or the other one, try both.
end = time.process_time()
print(f'{(end - start)/n_iter}')
```

This gives me similar results to the above for both functions.

Comment: It still 2% faster though ;)

Comment: @wim It's not. The `+- 21.8 ns` and `+- 13.8 ns` after the run times gives a range of `415-457 ns` for the first one, and `413-439 ns` for the second one. The two overlap entirely and their ranges aren't much different. Without doing a formal statistical test, I'm pretty confident that they are not statistically different. The actual test is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: I was kidding - apparently my sense of humour missed the mark here :P

Comment: Or, if you're not a data scientist who's installed things with anaconda, ipython.

Comment: @wim not really, just gave me a chance to point out the statistical nature of run times, so I took it!

Answer (score 2):

The name of the function is totally unrelated, because python namespaces are implemented using dicts, which are hash tables... so the name is converted to a hash for lookup which should be the same size and speed for all names.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for how Python implements namespaces but wasn't fast enough...